# Add new item into Windows context menu (right click menu)

Tags: python, c#, windows, contextmenu

According to [Rajeev's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268206/windows-right-click-context-menu-sub-menu), i want to do the same. I want to create new item in the Windows context menu and after pointing on it, it will open sub menu in which will be clickable items which will take a action written in C# or Python.

I didn't find anything (at least) nearly similar.

Comment: maybe not directly answering your question, but you can have a look at this related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders

Answer (score 0):

this is my idea : you can create an application getting parametr. and you can add new item in content menu winodws With Application [FileMenu Tools] , see this: https://superuser.com/questions/55731/adding-items-to-a-files-right-click-menu-in-windows-explorer